# Pass integers as parameters of a function

Tags: python

I have the following function :

```
def test_prod(interval1, interval2):

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) ' \
              'FROM `use` ' \
              'WHERE `usepcd` = 2 ' \
              'AND year(`uw_datetime_end`) = year(now()) ' \
              'AND uw_datetime_end >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) day - INTERVAL %i week ' \
              'AND uw_datetime_end < CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) day - INTERVAL %i week ' \
              % interval1 \
              % interval2
        cursor.execute(sql)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
        print(row)

    return row
```

I tried to use the function with two integers (for the two `INTERVAL %i week` statements)

```
stock = test_prod(1,0)
```

But when I do it tells me :

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

I tried to change the %i for %s, but it didn't change anything,I tried to put commas around the parameters of the function, but nothing worked, what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Do *not* format SQL strings like that: some day, that will go horribly wrong.

Comment: Yes ? How then ?

Comment: What is your SQL engine?

Comment: Ok, I will try to change it, I use MySQL.

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/ is a good place to start re: understanding the problem and its solutions.

Comment: @9769953 It *could* work, if the result of the first one contained appropriate placeholders for the second to operate on. `'%s %%s' % "foo" % "bar" == "foo bar"`. But ultimately irrelevant, as this is not a safe way to create SQL queries in the first place.